# Is it possible to configure after-deployment behavior for a WAR (or EAR)?

Tags: java, deployment

When I'm deploying a WAR (or EAR) to an application server I have to be sure that the environment (everything **around** the AS) is ready for my application. Is it possible to instruct AS to execute certain Java classes right after deployment, and report a deployment problem if one of them reports a failure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement [ServletContextListener](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) and register it with [`<listener-class>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/app_events.html#178122) inside your web.xml

Comment: What if it's EAR without `web.xml` at all? I mean, is there any more __generic__ approach?

Comment: @Vincenzo: Note that the title of your question is misleading then :)

Answer (score 1):

> What if it's EAR without web.xml at all? I mean, is there any more generic approach?

I'll put my answer back then :) To my knowledge, there is nothing standardized in Java EE for that so the answer is "it depends on what your application server has to offer". For *example*, with WebLogic you can create [`ApplicationLifecycleListener`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/javadocs/weblogic/application/ApplicationLifecycleListener.html) classes.

Depending on the complexity of the checks you want to perform, it might be simpler to create some kind of status page deployed as part of the application and check it after deployment (that you could poll later regularly to check the health of your app).

For complex needs, using a real monitoring solution might be a better choice.

Comment: This is the solution we're using for PHP projects: [phpRack.com](http://www.phpRack.com). It does exactly what you said, creating a dedicated monitoring page inside the application. So that you have to worry about tests only, not about how to run them and deliver results (to tester or to Maven/Ant/Phing). I was interested whether something similar exists for java.. Looks like it doesn't, right? (a good chance to create it :)

Comment: @Vincenzo: Yes, something in the spirit of http://phpRack.com/. I'm not aware of something equivalent (it would be worth discussing what such a thing should check though). And as I said, for more complex needs, I'd consider real monitoring solutions like Nagios, ZenOSS, Hyperic, etc.